# How to test nested promise store actions

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

How to test nested promise method written in vue component written in method

as you can see here that cancel method is nested promise so how to write test case using vue test utils & jest

```
<template>
  <b-button variant="danger" @click="cancel">Cancel</b-button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    cancel() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch('cancel')
        .then(() => {
          this.$store
            .dispatch('getdata')
            .then(() => {})
            .catch(() => {});
          this.$emit('closeModel');
        })
        .catch(() => {});
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using flush-promises? https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-async-components.html

Comment: No i am not using flush-promises, we can but jest coverage will not cover
`.catch(() => {});` so how to sure jest coverage also fullfil

Comment: I would try flush-promises first, but I agree, I've had similar problems where flush-promises can't await nested promises